# Not able to test component method executed inside componenWillMount

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, sinon, enzyme

I have a component called App and inside this component I have a method called `fetchContent`. This method is called inside my componentWillMount method and I'm trying to verify if it is indeed called when I mount my component. Below is my method:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  fetchContent = (current) => {
   ...do some stuff in here
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchContent('techcrunch');
  }
```

As you can see, I'm using an arrow function instead of binding it to the component in my constructor. I need to bind it because it is also a method called for a click event.

However, when I try to run my unit test in this component, I can't get my spy/stub to work, because it throws an error saying:

`TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property fetchContent as function`

Below is my unit test:

```
it('should fetch the content when component mounts', () => {
    sinon.spy(App.prototype, 'fetchContent');
    wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.instance().fetchContent).to.have.been.calledOnce;
});
```

However, if my method is not bound or is not using an arrow function, it works fine.

Any ideas how to accomplish it?

Comment: You can use `jest.fn()` to mock the component method and then check whether the mocked function is called or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well I need 50 rep on stackoverflow to comment so this won't answer your actual question of why it isn't getting stub.

Anyway, given that situation, if I were you, I would not stub the actual implementation, `this.fetchContent`, but rather test what the property does.

So an example if `fetchContent` were to do something like this:

```
fetchContent = (current) => {
  this.setState({foo: current});
}
```

I would then test that state.foo has what you passed in `fetchContent` when the component mounts.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to make sure appropriate function calls occur as a side effect of another function, I like approaching it like this:

```
const wrapper   = shallow(<App />)
const component = wrapper.instance()

// either
sinon.spy(component, 'fetchContent');
expect(wrapper.instance().fetchContent).to.have.been.calledOnce;

// or
const restore          = component.fetchContent
component.fetchContent = jest.fn()
const mock             = component.fetchContent

component.componentWillMount()

expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled()
container.fetchContent = restore
```

Instead of using `enzyme.mount`, you can just test the side effects of `componentWillMount` and trust React to do its job firing lifecycle methods appropriately.